# If I start a Firebase trace and don't ever stop it? Will it cause issues on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I'm using [Firebase Performance Monitoring SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/) (on Android, but will also on iOS) and for one particular use case it's hard to know whether a started [Trace](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/perf/metrics/Trace) will ever be stopped. And given there is no apparent way how to cancel an already running trace, I figured I'd just start it every single time and then eventually stop it only under the right circumstances. (and leave intact otherwise).

Shall I expect issues? I figured the trace would not be logged if not stopped (that's what I need), but I'm scared of memory leaks and also some general resource waste.

I could also potentially clear the reference to the trace and hopefully let GC sweep it (provided Firebase doesn't store a reference to each running Trace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start a trace but never stop it, a very small amount of memory will be leaked for that Trace object as it waits for you to stop it.  It's probably not a big deal, but a leak is a leak.  Clearing the reference when you would like to abandon the trace will allow it to be garbage collected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are there plans to allow cancel running traces?

Comment: And one more thing. I’m looking into all of this because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47204460/419449 . I know it’s a long shot, I noticed that Firebase does some automatic app launch tracing (although it doesn’t seem to be working in our app atm..I’m looking into this)..Do you have any comments on how this works? Sadly the Android SDK is not open source 

Comment: For the app start trace, the SDK uses a ContentProvider.onCreate() as the start point, and the first Activity.onResume() as the stop point.  That's documented here.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/automatic

Comment: Yup, I saw that. But I don’t really follow how that works. The content provider is created right after the process starts, right? What if that happens as a result of incoming notification and the user opens the app after some time, but before Android kills the process again? 

Comment: I updated my answer - something changed in the implementation recently that prevents all traces from being held internally until they're stopped.  As far as app start time is concerned, that's a different question, so please ask it separately.  I had the same concerns when working with the engineers, and I'll follow up with them to get a better sense of how it works.

Comment: Thank you! I created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261735/how-does-firebase-app-start-time-profiling-work-on-android

Comment: So can I start a trace and decide later whether I want it to be collected or not, simply by stopping it (collected) or just clearing the reference (not collected)?