# How to track the time elapsed between when user taps on icon in launcher and when an Activity displays?

Tags: android

I'm trying to quantitatively measure launch time performance of an Android app and I struggle to come up with a way how to measure the time elapsed between when the user presses the launcher icon and when the Activity actually displays.

I'd like to get this as close to what users see as possible, so simply tracking the time between `Activity.onCreate` and `Activity.onResume` won't do the trick.

Starting the timer in `Application` class doesn't work either because it can be started by other means plus can be already running when the user presses the launcher.

Do you have any ideas how to implement something like this?

Here are my summarized requirements:

1. Be as close as possible to the perceived app launch time
2. Only measure the start time when going from launcher to the main activity (and not when app is started after tapping on notification,...).
3. Consider a fact that there can be some other Activities launched before the actual main Activity (e.g. splash screen)
4. I need to have access to this data from code and send it to an analytics service (can't just use ADB or so)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using a background service to listen to running tasks by calling  [getRunningTasks(1)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)).
(As for API21 it will return only your application tasks so its good enough.)

As soon as you detect your app is running, save the current timestamp and stop your loop.
On your launcher Activity, save the current timestamp on the OnResume method and calculate the time passed.

Your service should look something like this...

```
boolean stop = false;
 while(!stop)
 { 
      List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
      ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
     if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals("Your package name"))
     {
      //Save current time here
      stop = true;
     }
 }
```

You can also have a look at [getAppTasks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getAppTasks()). Maybe it would be better than the getRunningTasks method. Haven't used it so far...

Comment: I thought about having some sort of service monitoring the state of the app, but that doesn't seem like a viable solution either.
How about a real cold start..At that point the app won't be running. (don't consider boot receiver) And what about when people/OS kill it..
I wan't to use it in a production app, it's not like a proof of concept thing..It should have zero to none side effects on how the app runs now  (i.e. no foreground services and stuff like that )

Comment: Take a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538408/2402866

Comment: The process can start way earlier (notification,..) and not just when the user opens the app

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its late and maybe you know:

You can use [Firebase Performance Monitor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android).

After integrating Firebase Performance Monitoring in your app you don't need to write any code. It automatically measures app startup time and no need to do more work.

You can see the data in your Firbase Console-> Performance -> under Traces > _app_start > Duration

[According to Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/auto_duration-traces-metrics_ios-android?platform=android#app-start) :

> app start traces measures the time between when the user opens the
> app and when the app is responsive

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you can see that time on log-cat. Logcat actually tells you the elapsed time between user tapping an display of first activity. You dont need to write any code to track time.