# How to prevent memory leak on Firebase trace on iOS without calling stop?

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I'm planning to use [Firebase Performance Monitoring SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/) in a iOS project of mine and I'm trying to trace a specific journey with different outcomes. For example, assume I want to track the time taken for a user to reset their password. I will [start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/custom_traces-metrics?platform=ios) tracking when the user begins their reset password journey and I want to stop the trace on a successful password reset. My issue is that if the user abandons the password reset because they remember their password and cancels it, I do not call the stop() method of the trace. From what I understand in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202589/if-i-start-a-firebase-trace-and-dont-ever-stop-it-will-it-cause-issues-on-andr) it will begin to cause a memory leak until stopped. I'm trying to think of a way to gracefully end/stop/discard the trace and stop a memory leak without calling the stop() method as it will cause incorrect data to be reported.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Right now I have a swift class that handles tracing with the following inside of it.

```
private var passwordResetTrace: Trace?

func startPWResetTrace() {
    passwordResetTrace.startTrace(name: "passwordTimeTrace")
}

func stopPWResetTrace() {
    passwordResetTrace.stop()
}
```

I'm not sure if it's something as simple as just setting the Trace to nil, that seems not enough in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from `FIRTrace` sources, [they do clean up resources](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/9f36662ee8b71dd6b6e15e5b57ce30daefafb832/FirebasePerformance/Sources/Timer/FIRTrace.m#L117) in `dealloc`. Moreover, `FIRTrace` even has private `cancel()` method which [doesn't do anything related](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/9f36662ee8b71dd6b6e15e5b57ce30daefafb832/FirebasePerformance/Sources/Timer/FIRTrace.m#L182) to resource management. I think that's enough to assume just releasing the trace without stopping won't result in memory leak.